# What's the right way to create a date in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, date, calendar

I get confused by the Java API for the Date class. Everything seems to be deprecated and links to the Calendar class. So I started using the Calendar objects to do what I would have liked to do with a Date, but intuitively it kind of bothers me to use a Calendar object when all I really want to do is create and compare two dates.

Is there a simple way to do that? For now I do

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
cal.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
Date date = cal.getTime(); // get back a Date object
```

Comment: @Bohemian The code has a problem: the milliseconds of the created `Date` object are set to whatever the internal clock is, when the code is executed (you can get around that, if you call `cal.setTimeInMillis(0)` before `cal.set(...)` - results in kind of silly code though). Just ran into that problem...

Comment: @kratenko ok good point. And Calendar is a mess anyway :/

Comment: `Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();` seems to work

Answer (score 110):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date d = sdf.parse("21/12/2012");
```

But I don't know whether it should be considered more *right* than to use Calendar ...

Comment: I think this is even slower as it has to parse a string.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right, but it's also the most "readable" way to make a date, so if you aren't doing it inside a loop ...

Comment: Just remember that SimpleDateFormat is not Synchronized. If you reuse the instance and two methods access the same SimpleDateFormat  you will cause bugs.

Answer (score 37):

The excellent [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library is almost always a better choice than Java's Date or Calendar classes.  Here's a few examples:

```
DateTime aDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
DateTime anotherDate = new DateTime(anotherYear, anotherMonth, anotherDay, ...);
if (aDate.isAfter(anotherDate)) {...}
DateTime yearFromADate = aDate.plusYears(1);
```

Comment: I took this suggestion and this worked great for me. The standard Java date classes are a true pain to use. I used jodatime and was done with my task utilizing dates in less than a minute! Thanks.

Comment: Updated website for Joda-time: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Answer (score 15):

You can try [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: +1 for this - Joda time is in my view infinitely better than the built-in Java date functionality.